# Sort the list without changing order in scala

Tags: scala

```
val a = List((2,5,1),(3,8,4), (5,4,3) ,(9,1,2))
```

I want output as a different list which is in sorted order based on the middle element of each tuple in the list and first & third tuple's order should not be changed. Its like swapping the second tuple only.

Expected answer is:

```
List((2,1,1), (3,4,4) , (5,5,3), (9,8,2))
```

Comment: It's my bad. I have edited it. thanks for correcting. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As shown below, you can sort the 2nd items separately and zip them together

```
a.zip(a.map(_._2).sorted).map{ case((a,b,c), sortedB) => (a,sortedB,c)}
// res = List((2,1,1), (3,4,4), (5,5,3), (9,8,2))
```

Answer (score 6):

`zip` and `unzip` and their variants are your friends for this kind of thing.

```
val x = List((2,5,1),(3,8,4), (5,4,3) ,(9,1,2))
val y = x.unzip3 match {
  case (a,b,c) => (a, b.sorted,c).zipped.toList
}
```